# Fetch record based on role rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am using **Devise** and **Cancan** for my projects and it works fine.
There are **users** table in database.
There are 3 types of role

```
->Admin
->Publishers
->Players
```

Now i want to fetch all record from **users table** expect **admin's record.**

I am little confused how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If role is a string in user table:

```
scope :with_role, lambda{|role_name| where(:role => role_name) }
```

If user belongs_to role:

```
scope :with_role, lambda{|role_name| includes(:role).where(:roles => {:title => role_name}) }
```

And now you can fetch all admins:

```
User.with_role('admin')
```